# Where can I get the number of days left for the Scratch Org to expire?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Is there any way to retrieve the number of remaining days for my scratch orgs to expire (individually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ScratchOrgInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_scratchorginfo.htm) table holds this data. It doesn't show the number of days left, though, it just shows the expiration date. You'd have to calculate manually yourself. The force:org:list command in sfdx will also show the expiration dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
sfdx force:org:list --all
```

You'll see all the details related to all orgs ,including the alias,username and expiration date for scratch org
[image]